# Pegando Event Detail do Elastic Beanstalk com Python e Boto

Tags: python, amazon-aws

Eu tenho um script para deploy feito com `Fabric` e `Boto` para fazer deploy de aplicações no `AWS Beanstalk` e gostaria de printar os Event Details gerados no `beanstalk` no terminal durante o deploy. Alguém sabe se isso é algo possível? Se sim, como pode ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ficar pedindo os eventos até o status do seu environment mudar de `"Updating"` para `"Ready"`.
Para buscar os eventos, use [`describe_events`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/beanstalk.html#boto.beanstalk.layer1.Layer1.describe_events):

```
eb = boto.connect_beanstalk()                                                  
resposta = eb.describe_events(environment_name='seu_environment', max_records=10)
eventos = resposta['DescribeEventsResponse']['DescribeEventsResult']['Events'] 
for evento in eventos:                                                         
    print evento['Severity'], \                                                
        'em', datetime.fromtimestamp(evento['EventDate']), \                   
        ':', evento['Message']
```